# Scrolling inside a iframe among multiple scrolls

Tags: java, angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am working on a angular site and the test I run needs the user to scroll down to enter a text.

The problem is, the scroll is inside a iFrame and the iFrame has three sections where each section has it's own scroll bar. I want the scroll to happen in the last section scroll bar.

How can I focus my scroll to this? I use selenium/java.

I use the below code and my test is passing and I am not sure whether this is the correct approach to handle scroll.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,350)", "");
```

Image below: [image]

Comment: try to switch into the frame then scroll

Comment: I do that. Since there are three scrolls on the page, not sure how to focus on the last one as shown in the image.

Comment: can you please share url

Comment: I am afraid that the site is a paid site and you would need credentials to login and use it. Would be happy to share more screenshots of required.

Comment: you are using this : "((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,350)", "");" and is it working fine ?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Have you tried just entering text into the desired field or clicking it? I've generally found that I can enter text into whatever field I want, it will be scrolled to automatically.

Comment: Yes I just figured this. You can give it as an answer and i will chose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not need to focus on the scroll i need, because Selenium automatically scrolls until the element is found.